# Split a 2 column CSV and save to different files

Tags: python, csv

I have a headerless CSV file in this format:

```
A,value for A
B,value for B
C,value for C
...
```

Now I need to split each row, saving each value to a separate file, named after the first column for the value:

```
File        Value
A.txt       value for A
B.txt       value for B
C.txt       value for C
```

Notes: Values are non-English, so files have to be in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? Post your code and ask specific questions. SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.x, the `csv` library does not directly support utf-8 encoding. There is though a wrapper you can install that does:

```
import unicodecsv

with open('files.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    for row in unicodecsv.reader(f_input, encoding='utf-8'):
        with open('{}.txt'.format(row[0]), 'wb') as f_output:
            csv_output = unicodecsv.writer(f_output, encoding='utf-8')
            csv_output.writerow([row[1]])
```

You can install this using:

```
pip install unicodecsv
```

More information can be found here: [unicodecsv 0.14.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1)